# Не могу настроить ScrollView

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor, unity3d-ui

У меня есть сделанный по гайдам ScrollView, его структура такова:

```
Элемент ScrollView 
----- Элемент ScrollRect - ScrollRect, Mask
---------- Элемент Text - Text, Content Size Filter
```

Мне нужно, чтобы когда я изменял текст, он был в начале ScrollRect`а, однако [image: 1]
как видно на фото, он центрируется, как мне это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему:

```
После ScrollRect должен быть элемент Content
С элемента Text надо убрать ContentSizeFilter и повестить его на Content + добавь на content VerticalLayoutGroup
В VerticalLayoutGroup выбираем опцию - UpperCenter и в ректе контента изменяем pivot на x-0.5, y-1
Текст должен быть ребенком контента
```